# 3-col navigation menu with images

Tags: css, list, navigation

I am working on the css for a website and am trying to determine the best approach for the navigation menu.  The layout of the menu is as follows:

[image]

between col 1 and 2, and also between col 2 and 3 are double vertical lines, which because of their style will probably need to be an image.

SO, my question is this:

Semantically, all of these links are part of one unordered navigation list.  But, I can't find any way to create such a list using css only that will work in IE.  The images between list items only muddles it up more.  Is there a clean way to do this?

My second approach was to create 3  columns, and place a list in col 1 and col 3.  But this still seems messy with the image dividers.  I thought about using li:after to place the images, but IE7 doesn't recognize the "content" property.

Right now, it seems like the cleanest way to build this is without lists.  But then I feel like I'm losing proper semantics.  Is there a better approach that I'm not thinking of?  The layout is very tabular, so I could certainly make it a table . . .  : )

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an image illustrating what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I added the image.  Hopefully, my question makes more sense.  Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with creating two unordered lists on the sides and putting your logo in the middle??

Comment: For what its worth, you could justify having two distinct lists this way:  a list of products (necklaces, bracelets) and a list of company related information (events, about us).  Is support for IE7 a requirement for the project as requested by the client?  If not, there's nothing wrong with letting it degrade gracefully.

Comment: thanks all.  for now, i have implemented it using two separate ul's.  if i do want to support IE7, though, how would you approach this?  would you just place the dotted lines with a separate z-index, behind the lists?  or would you forget about the list structure altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can make one UL with four LIs and give absolute position to first and last li (maybe "events" and "about us"). This can be achieved by pseudo selectors :first-child and :last-child.

Answer (score 0):

I solved as follows for links where you substitute the names you need and the class image with the image and your measurements.

```
   <style type="text/css">

   ul{
     width:400px;
 height:200px;
 }
   ul li{
 border-top:1px solid gray;
 border-bottom:1px solid gray;
 display:block;
 height:99x;
 width:100px;
}
  .left{
    float:left;
    }

  .right{
    float:right;
   }
  .second{
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:-100px;
   }
   .image{
background:red;
border-left:3px double gray;
border-right:3px double gray;
display:block;
float:left;
height:200px;
width:194px;}
    </style>


    <body>
      <ul>
    <li class="left"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="left second"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="image"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="right second"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    <body>
```

I hope I can help. A greeting.

Comment: Thanks.  One of my problems is that I have to use images for all of the lines, as they are not an exact css style or a web color.  So, I can't use the borders as above.  It then becomes a bit weird to me to have these images interspersed throughout the list.

Comment: You can use backgrounds multiples for fix in the top and the bottom of the li element a image